# Unable to sort csv file using key lambda function

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that I am trying to sort using python.

| VIP | PROTOCOL | PORT | SG | HEALTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vip1 | http | 80 | sg1 | yes |
| vip2 | ssl | 443 | sg2 | no |
| vip3 | http | 80 | sg3 | no |

I tried following to sort based on column 'PROTOCOL' but it is not producing result.

```
with open(svg.csv,'r') as open_file:
  rdr=csv.reader(open_file)
  sortcsv=sorted(rdr,key=lambda x:x[2])
open_file.close()
with open(svg.csv,'w') as file_out:
  writr=csv.writer(file_out)
  writr.writerows(sortcsv)
```

I also need to add a vlookup on this .csv file using python. Can you please direct me how I can do a vlookup in python.

Comment: What is `r` here? It should be `'r'` when you're reading in the CSV file, and `'w'` when you're writing it out.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use `pandas`? Using `pandas` `DataFrame`  can be relatively easier to do what you're asking, regardless sorting a column or vlookup. For vlookup, try reference this website tutorial: [How to Do a vLookup in Python using pandas](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-do-a-vlookup-in-python-using-pandas/).

Comment: When asking CSV questions, it's usually best to provide the data is plan text format. What is a "vlookup"?

Comment: @mechanical_meat: `r` is the I/O mode the file is opened in. It means "read". See the documentation for the file `open()` function.

Comment: @martineau: the code just had `r` in it when I saw it, with no quotes.

Comment: @mechanical_meat: I see — apologies. The filename is wrong as well — it's missing quotes too.

Answer (score 2):

The `PROTOCOL` column is indexed with a `1`, not a `2` because it is the second column — i.e. you need to use `key=lambda x: x[1])` to sort on its values. Note you don't want also be sorting the header row because it will likely no longer be the first row of data after doing a `sort()`, so it has to be removed and handled separately.

The code below fixes both those issues. I don't know how to add a vlookup on this CSV data because I don't know what the term means. I think it's an Excel spreadsheet function but you haven't specified what it does or how it works.

```
import csv

with open('svg.csv', 'r', newline='') as open_file:
    reader = csv.reader(open_file)
    header = next(reader)
    sortedcsv = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: x[1])
    sortedcsv.insert(0, header)

with open('svg_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_out:
    writer = csv.writer(file_out)
    writer.writerows(sortedcsv)
```